# C# COM Interop: How to translate instructions from C++?

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, com-interop

I am trying to translate the COM Interop instructions given by my camera manufacturer for C++ to C#.

They write:

> To obtain the interface, you use the normal COM functions to ask for the specific interface you need from the capture filter. 
>   For example:
>
> ```
> IBaseFilter* pSourceFilter;
> ...
> CComQIPtr<IManufacturersInterface> pKs( pSourceFilter );
> pKs->SetShutterSpeed( ssAuto1 );
> ```

They also give an interface signature and a Guid. The signature looks like

```
interface IManufacturersInterface: IUnknown
{
    // more stuff
    HRESULT SetShutterSpeed( [in] eShutterSpeed lShutter );
    // more stuff
}
```

which I translated into C# as

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("926ddb16-3c8e-476c-9068-eb4555a99231")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IManufacturersInterface
{
    // more stuff
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetShutterSpeed([In] eShutterSpeed lShutter);
    // more stuff
}
```

From [another source](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/04/webcam-control-with-wpf-or-how-to.html) I got a similar DirectShow wrapper to access the camera in the first place, including an COM-imported interface `IBaseFilter`. How would I now translate the first example?

I tried

```
IManufacturersInterface control = sourceFilter as IManufacturersInterface; // sourceFilter is declared as IBaseFilter
control.SetShutterSpeed(eShutterSpeed.ssAuto1);
```

but control is null after the cast.

Sorry if I am vague, I have no real clue what I am doing here. This is the first time I had to use COM Interop. It shows, hm? =)

Comment: Instead of using 'as' operator, use direct cast - it will of course not work and give you an exception. Exception should provide more details - my guess is that wrapper class that you are using does not support the interface in question.

Comment: @VinayC: You are right, thanks! I'll look into that wrapper then. So my guess that the line starting with "CComQIPtr" was a cast was not that bad. =) Maybe post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You can always flag the comment as good. However, you may want to consider Grzenio'solution - it will solve many of your pains!

Comment: Yeah CComQIPtr<Interface> will do a query interface 'cast' of the com object when assigned - it is also a managed object so it will handle all the appropriate add/un refs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do com interop is to let Visual Studio create the interop for you - I used it with many different com objects and never had any issues with it. To get started, in your C# project select Add Reference and select the tab COM, find the camera manufacturer's object in the list and you should be done. You can now use the com objects as if they were native C#.

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not seems to be an entry for it. Thanks, though =)

Comment: If there is no entry for it then probably it hasn't been registered and you can't use it. Please make sure that your camera's software was correctly installed.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work, he won't have a type library for COM interfaces like that.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Do you maybe know a tutorial on how to deal with "COM interfaces like that"? As VinayC has suggested, the interface I was looking for is not supported, but I have a hard time troubleshooting this.

Comment: @Jens: I don't know of any.  Everybody avoids this because it is so error prone and hard to maintain.  Write a managed wrapper in the C++/CLI language instead so you can use native COM.